# Displaying images, which are stored in a string, on a JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, struts-1

I am using the below mentioned code on my JSP:

```
<%
List eCCategoryList = form.getCategoryList();

//Map<String, String> catNameImgMap = (Map<String, String>) session.getAttribute("catNameImgMap");

Map catNameImgMap = (Map) form.getBlogIdNameMap();

String strImage = "";

Iterator it = eCCategoryList.iterator();

ECircularCategory category = null;

int counter = 0;

while (it.hasNext()) {
    category = (ECircularCategory) it.next();
    strImage = (String) catNameImgMap.get(category.getName());

%>
```

`strImage` contains image which I need to display on my JSP. I tried displaying the images like:

```
<img src="<%=strImage%>" alt="Test Image 1" width="270" height="190"/>
```

but the above code is not working a simple blank space is shown and nothing else, I need to display the images on my JSP page each of which are stored in the `strImage` string, how do I do it?

Please suggest.

Comment: Please improve formatting of the code.

Comment: Are you fetching the whole image data as some encoded string (like Base64) or just the name of the image or the URL of the image from the call `strImage = (String) catNameImgMap.get(category.getName());`?

Comment: Can you also paste the content of one of the `strImage` variable?

Comment: Just the name of the images is displayed in strImage string eg. http://m.sears.com/ecircular/SearsLocalAd.jpg is the string i got by displaying strImage. Also please tell about proper formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSTL tag:

```
<img src="<c:url value="<%=strImage%>"/> alt="Test Image 1" width="270" height="190"/>
```

Here is a good [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) about JSTL.

Hope it helps...

Comment: the above code works an I was able to display the images as well but <%=strImage%> throws a nullpointer exception due to which half of the page appears other half is blank, though <%=strImage%> has images stored in it. So is it that the value attribute in c:url accepts some other format of printing string, or another way around. Plz suggest.